# Firefox how to search for text in devtools -> network -> response?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

how do i search for specific text in firefox devtools -> network -> response ? when i do ctrl+F nothing happens, and when i right-click, search isn't one of the options..
[image]

by comparison it's easy in Chrome devtools, just pressing ctrl+F brings up a search menu..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[As of Firefox 104.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1779164), the global request search in the Network Monitor that lets you search for arbitrary information within all requests also searches within responses.
This search can be toggled by clicking the magnifying glass button within its toolbar.

[image: Request search in the Network Monitor]

Besides that feature, you can also open the request within a new tab by right-clicking it and choosing *Open in New Tab*. When the request is displayed in the new tab, open the source view (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or via the page's context menu > *View Page Source*). Within the source view, you can then search like you normally search within a page, i.e. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, for example.

Comment: it has been fixed now :) pressing Ctrl+F brings up a search menu in 115.5.0esr

Comment: Yep, it got added in Firefox 104.0. Thanks for the hint! I've updated the answer accordingly.